# Быстрый генератор подмножеств заданной мощности исходного множества

Tags: c#, c++

Предположим у меня есть массив чисел `A = {1,2,3,...,n}`

Нужно сгенерировать все подмножества заданного массива мощностью `m`

Скажем `A = {1,2,3,4}, m = 3`

Тогда подмножества: `{1,2,3} {2,3,4} {1,3,4} {1,2,4}`

Как реализовать такой алгоритм на C# или C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На С++11:

```
template <typename T>
class SubSeq
{
public:
    class Index
    {
    public:
        Index(size_t seq_size, size_t subseq_size) : ss(seq_size), s(subseq_size), data()
        {
            data.reserve(s + 1);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i)
                data.push_back(i);
            data.push_back(ss);
        }
        bool next() { return next(s-1); }
        bool next(size_t i) {
            data[i]++;
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < s; ++j) data[j] = data[j - 1] + 1;
            if (data[s - 1] >= data[s]) {
                if (i > 0) return next(i-1);
                else       return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        size_t operator[] (size_t i) { return data[i]; }
    private:
        size_t              ss, s;
        std::vector<size_t> data;
    };

    SubSeq(const std::vector<T>& data, size_t subseq_size)
        : seq_size(data.size()), subseq_size(subseq_size),
          data(data), index(data.size(), subseq_size),
          ended(subseq_size > data.size() || subseq_size == 0)
    {}
    std::vector<T> next() {
        std::vector<T> v;
        v.reserve(subseq_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < subseq_size; ++i)
            v.push_back(data[index[i]]);
        ended = !index.next();
        return v;
    }
    bool end() { return ended; }
    void start() {
        index = Index(seq_size, subseq_size);
        ended = subseq_size > seq_size || subseq_size == 0;
    }

private:
    size_t seq_size, subseq_size;
    std::vector<T> data;
    Index  index;
    bool   ended;
};
```

Использование:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
SubSeq<int> ss(v, 3);
while (! ss.end()) {
   std::vector<int> s = ss.next();
}
```

в s будут векторы {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, ..., {2,3,4}

Просто уже был готовый код.

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
public Array ArraySub(int[] param)
    {
        int[] a = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        //В метод можно передать данные извне, не очень красиво, но работает
        if (param.Any())
        {
            a = param;
        }
        //шаг выборки
        int step = 3;

        int lenght = step;
        int i = 0;
        //Здесь будут ссылочные данные ArraySegment, содержимое меняется вместе с родительским массивом
        Array subA = new Array[] {};
        //А это новый массив, с скопированными данными
        Array[] subClone = new Array[] {};
        while (lenght <= a.Length)
        {
            subA.SetValue(new ArraySegment<int>(a, lenght-step, step), i);
            subClone.SetValue(a.Skip(lenght-step).Take(step).ToArray(),i);

            i++;
            lenght++;
        }


        //возвращать можем как первоначальный массив так и subA или subClone
        return a;
    }
```

и почитайте про массивы в msdn.